# Canvas images getting trash collected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

im building a multi frame TK application, the problem is that when i set the canvas image for background it is getting trash collected.

```
class template (Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        myFrames=(startpage, identLeave)

        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand= True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in myFrames:

            frame = F(container,self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            
        
        self.show_frame(startpage)
    
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame= self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class startpage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        
        SetBG(parent,r'src\images\1.png')
        
        test= Button(parent, text="test").grid(row=0,column=0)

class identLeave(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        Frame.__init__(self,parent)


app = template()
app.mainloop()
```

this is how im building the canva

```
def SetBG(parent, path):

    #loading Image into system (path is relative to folder from Main.py)
    loadIMG = Image.open(path)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(loadIMG)

    #setting canva with image resolution
    backg = Canvas(parent,width=1920,height=1080)
    backg.grid(sticky="nsew",columnspan=30,rowspan=30)
        
    #setting image inside the canva for display
    backg.create_image(0,0, image=img, ancho='nw')

    return(backg)
```

on a similar i had with buttons i just overpass the garbage collector by using button.image(img) but in this case i was unable to find something similar for canvas.

i am also open for other approaches on how to set the background images for the application

Comment: Something simple as `self.img` should work, or `backg.image = img` or maybe even `return img`.

Comment: thanks a lot the return of the img did work